# Getting the org-mode manual in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, manpage

How can I get access to the org-mode manual from within emacs?

I've seen this suggested:

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> Org Mode <kbd>RET</kbd>

But the org-mode manual isn't available that way in emacs 24.3.1. Is there a melpa package or something similar I can install to get the org-manual in emacs info mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu, Debian or a related distributions, do:

```
apt-get install emacs24-common-non-dfsg
```

While the Org Mode manual is part of the standard Emacs distributions, Debian, Ubuntu and related distributions do not include it in their Emacs packages, as their understanding of truly free software is subtly different from the FSF's.  You'll need to install it separately.

Answer (score 2):

In Section
***"How do I update the info manual pages to the latest org-mode version?"*** of http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html there is a hint where you find the texi-files.

You can build the info manual pages from these ones.