# Updating infopath for org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, manpage, info

With emacs24 I'm using org-mode 8.2.8 installed from the tar.gz file available on orgmode.org.

I'm trying to get the infopath loaded so that <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> Org Mode <kbd>RET</kbd> will give me the org manual.

The org faq mentions [two methods](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#update-info-manual-to-latest) - both of which make reference to `/path/to/org-mode/info` but there isn't any `info` directory in the 8.2.8 org-mode root directory, only a `doc` directory.

Compiling org-mode 8.2.8 with the `make` command from the org-mode 8.2.8 root directory builds the file /usr/share/org which seemingly contains the manual for org 8.2.8 but I'm not able to load that with neither methods mentioned in the FAQ.

Note: I've previously asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620774/getting-the-org-mode-manual-in-emacs). In that case I was using the version of org-mode that shipped with emacs24 and `apt-get install emacs24-common-non-dfsg` got me the man pages. This is a different case in which I'm using another version of org-mode than the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc directory contains org.texi. Add that to Info-directory-list.

```
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list "/path/to/org-mode/doc")
```

---

If info hasn't been loaded yet, use

```
(eval-after-load "info"
  '(progn
     (info-initialize)
     (add-to-list 'Info-directory-list "/path/to/org-mode/doc")))
```

or

```
(add-to-list 
 'Info-default-directory-list "/path/to/org-mode/doc")
```

Comment: That as well gives me the error "Symbol's value as variable is void: Info-directory-list" on emacs startup.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I have the first answer in my configuration, but that must work because info is loaded at some other point.

Comment: `(eval-after-load "info"
  '(progn
     (info-initialize)
     (add-to-list 'Info-directory-list "/path/to/org-mode/doc")))` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following "generic" solution to add a couple of Info paths:

```
(with-eval-after-load "info"
  (setq Info-directory-list
        `(,(expand-file-name
            (concat (file-name-directory (locate-library "org")) "../doc/"))
          "c:/cygwin/usr/share/info/"
          ,@Info-directory-list)))
```

(For Emacs 24.4, because of the `with-eval-after-load`)

Comment: That gives me the error "Symbol's value as variable is void: Info-directory-list" on emacs startup.

Comment: Right: it must be enclosed in an ```with-eval-after-load```. I edit my answer.

Comment: With that I get: `End of file during parsing: /home/andreas/.emacs`

Comment: @MajorBriggs Try adding a trailing parentheses.

Comment: Yes, sorry, missing paren. Edited the answer.